# boolean algebra minterm and maxterm expansion

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have an expression I'm not sure if i got right. The expression is 
$$
f(a,b,c) = a(b + c')
$$
what i did was multiplied them out and added missing variables.
which gave me 
$$
abc + abc' + ac'b + ac'b'
$$
I'm sure there is something wrong

I need to do minterm and maxterm expansion. I just don't know how.
Help :)

Answer (score 0):

ab+ac'
ab(c+c')+a(b+b')c'
abc+abc'+abc'+ab'c'
abc+abc'+ab'c'

use a truth table with 3 variables a,b,c
find followings
abc = 111 - 7
abc' = 110 - 6
ab'c'= 100 -4

Sum m (4, 6, 7)

therefore, maxterm M (0,1,2,3,5)